# playframework, can you route on hostname/subdomains?

Tags: playframework

We are porting a seam app(2 apps) to one play app to test out play right now(well, porting harder scenarios...so far, so good).

We would like to be able to route on hostname though for the root / directory.  For 
http://alvazan.com/ we want to route to our home.html page but for

http://*.premonitionx.com/ we want to route to the dashboard(which redirects to login page if not logged in).

Lastly, we want to route
http://premonitionx.com/ to redirect to alvazan.com web page.

Also, we would LOVE a route like

http://{company}.premonitionx.com/{project}/{release}

Is that even possible in the playframework????  In dev mode, we have these urls right now for developing in seam to use

http://{company}.dev.premonitionx.com such that we can test on our local machine and test out different companies, etc. etc.  (as you know many tests can't be tested if it is always localhost)

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some of the docs are more difficult to find for play. I couldn't find this in any of the real documentation but remembered it being part of a release...

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/releasenotes-1.1#routeHost

---

**Virtual hosting in routes**

The routes file now supports Host matching. this can be useful if action parameters must be extracted from the host parameter. For example, for a SAAS application, you could use:

```
GET    {client}.mysoftware.com/         Application.index
```

and then automatically retrieve the client value as for any other request parameter:

```
public static void index(String client) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So for http, sure.  for https, it won't work as you need a cert per domain and SSLEngine per domain and netty doesn't support using multiple SSLEngine from what I could tell.  I solved it with our own nio layer so that we can support multiple domains on this webserver instead https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces

Answer (score 0):

I think virtual hosting via the `routes` file is in play version 2.x *not* available anymore.

But what you can do is preparing a controller for proxying such requests. Here is my sample code which is working in play 2.8.x:

```
@Singleton
class VirtualHostsController @Inject() (
  langs: Langs,
  ccs: ControllerComponents
) extends AbstractController(ccs) with I18nSupport {

  private val logger = Logger(classOf[VirtualHostsController])

  def index() = Action { implicit request =>
    logger.info(s"Handling Virtual Hosts for ${request.host}")

    request.host match {
      case "localhost:9000" => Redirect(routes.SomeController.show())
      case "sub.domain.tld" => Redirect(routes.OtherController.show())
      case _ => InternalServerError("unknown domain")
    }
  }

}
```

And in the `routes` file you can write something like that:

```
GET     /                  controllers.VirtualHostsController.index()
```

Comment: thanks, but I ended up finding out why.  java doesn't really support it over https soooo, I created my own platform that hosts on every domain you want (with N SSL certs and an SSLEngine per cert).  The issue is most nio layers assume one!.  I parse the first hello SSL packet but do not modify.  so my webpieces webserver now supports it https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces while I don't think anyone else in java does as you have to parse the SSL hello packet.