# playframework, how to get domain into variable in routes file script snippet?

Tags: playframework

From this post, I am 99% there
[playframework, can you route on hostname/subdomains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144396/playframework-can-you-route-on-hostname-subdomains)

Now, I would LOVE to do the following (we have *.dev.alvazan.com and *.dev.alvazan.com pointing to 127.0.0.1 so developers have to be online OR edit their etc/hosts file)...

UNFORTUNATELY, the request object is null so how can I get the full host or domain that was requested????  then our file will work in production, QA, and on a developers machines with no changes.  best of all, developers are testing the real routes that will be used in production albeit they are swapped out via this one script that can never change(if only it worked)....

```
%{ 
  if(request.domain.contains(".dev.")
    || request.domain.startsWith(dev")) {
     alvazan = "dev.alvazan.com"
     premonitionx = "dev.premonitionx.com"
  } else if(request.domain.contains(".demo.")
      || request.domain.startsWith("demo")) {
     alvazan = "demo.alvazan.com"
     premonitionx = "demo.premonitionx.com"
  } else {
     alvazan = "alvazan.com"
     premonitionx = "premonitionx.com"
  }
}%
```

My routes would then be easily defined as

- GET {company}.${alvazan}/projects
- GET {company}.${alvazan}/project/{projectname}

which would be perfect!!!!

of course expanded, the route under the covers is really one of these three then depending on if the app is in prod, dev, or QA

- GET {company}.alvazan.com/projects
- GET {company}.dev.alvazan.com/projects
- GET {company}.demo.alvazan.com/projects

Exactly what we would be looking for.

NOTE: Hacking the playframework for us is a valid option so pointers there if there is no solutions here would be great!!!!!  This is my 3rd day now in the framework and I plan on diving into the code but was hoping it would be later, not so soon.

No, I don't want a way to swap environments...I want one environment to just work in three contexts with never having to change anything(well not for this routes file at least).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you just put the following in your routes:

```
GET {company}.alvazan.com/projects           /SomeController/method
```

then when you retrieve company if you had requested blah.dev.alvazan.com then company should be "blah.dev" and you'll then be able to route based on that

Alternative you should be able to do the following:

```
GET {company}.alvazan.com/projects           /SomeController/method
GET {company}.{env}.alvazan.com/projects     /SomeController/method
```

and then add String env to your controller method signature which should separate the env variable within the framework.

Reference on putting routes on domains for others reading this:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/releasenotes-1.1#routeHost

Comment: I really don't like the second alternative as then we are testing the {env} routes not production routes.  The first one would require that code I put in to be added to every single controller so this is not the optimal solution(I would rather hack play and try to figure out how to put the request into the routes file and have just the ONE snippet of logic for all controllers/urls).

Comment: I think we are going to end up going with {company}.${domain}/projects where domain is gotten from the play configuration so we swap it via the production, QA and development configs.  thanks.

Comment: thanks for the update Dean. Another thing you could do is just route everything to a single controller and then basically write a custom routing mechanism inside that controller (to call other controllers) but it is a pretty ugly solution.

Answer (score 2):

The request object is not null in the Controller - your snippet seems to be from a view/template.

I can do this in my controller

```
public static void url() {
    renderText(request.domain);
}
```

and it prints the domain part of the url nicely.

If you want to pass it to the view, you can do that by passing the request object in the render method:

```
public static void url() {
    render(request);
}
```

and then get to the request object in my view. 
Or did I misunderstand your problem?

I'm on play framework 1.2.4