# Using subdomains in Play framework 1.2.7

Tags: playframework-1.x, subdomain

I want to use subdomains in Play Framework 1.2.7

I have a routes file like so

```
GET     platform.mydomain.com.au/                             Application.platform
```

But I get a 404 when I try to navigate to the page. I would expect to at least get a Play specific error if something was wrong with the routes file.

I've seen evidence that it should be possible to use subdomains e.g.

Here:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/configuration
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/bclX-ZmXDcU

But nothing explicitly says it can/can't be done and if it can be done, how to do it.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9144506/2408961)? Also, how are you testing this? Locally or on a host that resolves to your (sub)domain? ( I'm assuming your real domain isn't "mydomain.com.au" :) )"

Comment: A bit late, but yes, testing it online